# How to get the maximum and minimum value of an ordered set / ordered map?

Tags: rust, b-tree, ordered-map, ordered-set

Rust's ordered set is a [`BTreeSet`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeSet.html):

> ```rust
> use std::collections::BTreeSet;
>
> // Type inference lets us omit an explicit type signature (which
> // would be `BTreeSet<&str>` in this example).
> let mut books = BTreeSet::new();
>
> // Add some books.
> books.insert("A Dance With Dragons");
> books.insert("To Kill a Mockingbird");
> books.insert("The Odyssey");
> books.insert("The Great Gatsby");
> ```

An ordered map is a [`BTreeMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html).

Since the set and map are ordered, there should be a way to get the maximal and minimal element contained. How do you get them?

Comment: Why not using a [`BinaryHeap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BinaryHeap.html) instead, which has a [`pop()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BinaryHeap.html#method.pop) method.

Comment: @hellow Yes, and probably more suitable is [`peek`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BinaryHeap.html#method.peek) if you only need to read the value. But I am not sure you can also get the other extremal value.

In my personal case, I was using `BTreeMap`s and the order was used to search inside the collection.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are no maximum or minimum member methods (inherent or from a trait) for this type.

The best way to have access to this information in O(log(n)) is to directly use an iterator, as mentioned by the developer team in [issue 31690 from GitHub](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31690):

```rust
let map: BTreeSet<V> = ...;
let min = map.iter().next();
let max = map.iter().next_back();
```

---

You can get the maximum and minimum of a collection by using the `Iterator::max()` and `Iterator::min()` methods, but doing this with an ordered set will browse the whole collection, ignoring the information that we have from the order.

```
// This will be very slow
map.iter().max()
map.iter().min()
```

[Issue 59947 has a benchmark](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/59947) showing the two alternatives for `BTreeMap`:

> ```
> test bench_first ... bench:           9 ns/iter (+/- 0)
> test bench_last  ... bench:           8 ns/iter (+/- 0)
> test bench_max   ... bench:       3,603 ns/iter (+/- 536)
> test bench_min   ... bench:       3,755 ns/iter (+/- 328)
> ```

Comment: Rust is not limited to std, https://crates.io/crates/min-max-heap

Comment: @Stargateur: Sure, but a heap is not a set/map, so while it may suits the OP needs, for this question it would not be suitable.

Comment: Of interest, I just came upon https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/65637 in TWiR.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Thanks. If I understand this commit, there will be `first` and `last` for the ordered set, and `first_key_value` and `last_key_value` for the ordered maps.
Since the merge is young, I guess we will have to wait a bit. (:

Comment: In 2020, The performance issue may not be there anymore! :)